# Ruby on Rails: Conditional Links using presence_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

I have two models, `User` and `Profile`, with `user_id` used as a foreign key to link them. I'd like to put a conditional statement in my footer that looks to see if the current user has a profile. If they do they will see a link to the edit page and, if they don't, to the create/new page.

I tried finding a solution online and I think using the presence_in?(object) method might work but, as a newbie, I don't quite get the syntax.

This is what I have so far if someone can help me get to the finish line :)

```
            <% if current_user.id (something something) %>
            <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_profile_path(:id => current_user) %></li>
            <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "New Profile", new_profile_path %></li>
            <% end %>
```

If my question is unclear please let me know and I'll provide a link to my Github page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do `<% if current_user.profile.present? %>` to check whether user's profile exists or not. You need have has_one association in User model to get this working e.g has_one :profile

Comment: 'has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy' is in my User model but I was still received 'undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass'  :(

Comment: Had to add 'if user_signed_in? &&' to get it to work.  Thanks for your help friend.

Comment: That means 'current_user' is nil and you are trying on call 'profile' on that nil object. Please check whether 'current_user' object is set properly. You can test this in console first. 
>> current_user = User.first
>> current_user.profile.present?